# Slow boot time due to firmware delay

Tags: linux-mint, boot, systemd, firmware

A couple days ago I installed Linux Mint Cinnamon version. I'm running linux-4.15.0-15-generic.

My systemd-analyze looks like this.

`Startup finished in 42.849s (firmware) + 5.076s (loader) + 6.438s  (kernel) + 18.856s (userspace) = 1min 13.220s`

I don't understand why the firmware takes nearly 40 seconds to load. I guess the firmware needs to take as less time as possible.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it relates to the system’s EFI (see the answer for details); this isn’t about Unix or Linux.

Answer (score 3):

The “firmware” part of the `systemd-analyze` report shows [the time spent initialising EFI](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/BootLoaderInterface/), *i.e.* the time elapsed between the instant you switched the power on (or the system rebooted) and the instant your boot loader started running. If you want to decrease that you’ll need to investigate your motherboard’s setup options.